# Can I Send a Text Message from My Computer to a Cell Phone?

Tags: sms

Is it possible to send a text message from a computer to a cell phone?  I'd like to be able to do this with Ruby, not quite sure what it entails.  After seeing GrandCentral and Google Voice, it seems like it's not that bad.

Is it possible?  How do I get started!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's fairly trivial.

Depends on whether you want to pay or not; some providers offer email addresses for each number that is with them, otherwise you can get an account with an SMS gateway (find one in your country, or try clickatell) and then just buy credits. They'll have various interfaces: Email, HTTP, more.

Answer (score 1):

check smsroaming.com it provide services to send sms from website and also have desktop application for it. including iphone, blackberry and facebook application for it.

i hope they will help you to manage sms.

regards
Azy